# Get FeatureType from GeoServer layer

Tags: python, features, geoserver-rest-api

I am using the `gsconfig` package in Python to retrieve layers in a geoserver. Now my problem is, I need to know the `FeatureType` of each layer (Point, Polygon, Linestring) but I am unable to find the necessary information.

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog

cat = Catalog(url, username="username", password="password")
gs_layer = cat.get_layer(layer_name)

# how can I retrieve Information about the featureType from gs_layer?
```

I am working with `geoserver 2.18` and `python 3.7`.